# how to determine windows update level through IUpdate interface

Tags: c++, windows, updates

I want to count available "important" windows updates in a c++ program. 
When windows updates reports about available updates, it classifies them by level.
In vista the possible levels  are {important, recommended, optional}
XP : {high-priority, optional}

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/downloads/windowsupdate/updatelevels.mspx
I can't find a mechanism to get the level of an update (IUpdate) from SDK.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the [IUpdate::DownloadPriority property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386885(VS.85).aspx) might be the correct mechanism for getting the level of importance of each update.

This property will return an value shown in the [DownloadPriority enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee898382(PROT.10).aspx).  As mentioned in the documentation the the exact importance or difference between the priorities is up to the program that implements this interface; for example Vista defines each level as "important", "recommended" and "optional" whereas XP only implements "high-priority" and "optional", likely throwing the normal and low priority levels into the same bucket (would have to experiment to verify this).

Comment: At least on Windows 8.1, this is set as 2 (Normal) for every update installed. Unfortunately, the MsrcSeverity rating property is only set on Security updates -- which excludes some Windows Updates marked as "Important" in the WU UI.